# npm install doesn't create node_modules dir

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I have a node js application. In package.json I inserted the dependences, but when I execute 'npm install' the node_modules dir has a strange structure:

the dependences of my dependency are installed in the node_modules of my application. An example.
Consider this dependency graph

```
foo
-- a
+-- b
   -- c
   +-- d
      -- e
      -- f
         -- g
```

I expected this folder structure:

```
foo
 +--node_modules
             -- a
             -- b
                +--node_modules
                           -- c
                           +-- d
                              +--node_modules
                                          -- e
                                          -- f
                                          +--node_modules
                                                      -- g
```

Instead all modules are installed in

```
foo
 +--node_modules
          -- a
          -- b
          -- c
          -- d
          -- e
          -- f
          -- g
```

Comment: What is your question? Why is the directory structure different? Can you post your package.json and your install methodology/source?

Comment: It all depends on the NPM version that you have installed. Can you please check which version of NPM you have, by running ```npm --version```?

Answer (score -1):

It's OK, NPM now works in this way.

npm3 resolves dependencies differently than npm2.

While npm2 installs all dependencies in a nested way, npm3 tries to mitigate the deep trees and redundancy that such nesting causes. npm3 attempts this by installing some secondary dependencies (dependencies of dependencies) in a flat way, in the same directory as the primary dependency that requires it.

You can read about it there: https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3